# Exposing Rest API with Apache Camel - getting 404

Tags: apache-camel

I tried very simple Route:

```
    restConfiguration()
            .component("servlet");

    rest().get("/hello")
            .to("direct:hello");

    from("direct:hello")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Hello World")
            .transform().simple("Hello World");
```

And indeed, when lunching  my spring boot application I can see that the route listens to it:
[enter image description here][1]

*2021-04-14 15:03:31.759  INFO 25248 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.InternalRouteStartupManager    : Route: route1 started and consuming from: direct://hello
2021-04-14 15:03:31.760  INFO 25248 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.InternalRouteStartupManager    : **Route: route2 started and consuming from: servlet:/hello**
2021-04-14 15:03:31.768  INFO 25248 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Total 2 routes, of which 2 are started
2021-04-14 15:03:31.768  INFO 25248 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.7.1 (camel-1) started in 220ms*

However, when I tried reaching this address, I get 404 error.

*{
"timestamp": "2021-04-14T12:17:11.975+00:00",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "",
"path": "/hello"
}*

and also  in my console:
*2021-04-14 15:17:11.973  WARN 25248 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : **No mapping for GET /hello***

Any idea how to solve it?
I would say here that I googled this issue and solution like using "camel.component.servlet.mapping.context-path=/*
" or using "camel" prefix didn't work for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

create a bean like that any configuration class

```
  @SpringBootApplication
    public class DemoApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        }
    
        @Bean
        public ServletRegistrationBean camelServletRegistrationBean() {
            ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CamelHttpTransportServlet(), "/*");
            registration.setName("CamelServlet");
            return registration;
        }}
```

for example camel rest and spring boot : https://github.com/erayerdem/camelrest

Answer (score -1):

Mine problem was because I was migrate from Camel 2.
The old config was : camel.component.servlet.mapping.context-path
From Camel 3 it should be this: camel.servlet.mapping.context-path

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).